# Article (the, a) beauty: which is correct?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

Should one say "Dentistry is related to beauty" or "Dentistry is related to the beauty"?

Is the definite article needed or not?

Comment: It's related to beauty: you don't need 'the'. (I would love to know *how* it's related!)

Comment: Beautiful smiles are part of beauty

Comment: Oh I see! I thought you were comparing it with music, poetry, painting...

Comment: Unless you're using a count usage (He bowled a couple of beauties / He bowled Atherton with a beauty), 'a beauty' is literary. _She possesses a beauty which is hard to describe in words,_ // 'The beauty' needs specific reference if non-count: _the beauty of technology / divine love / the Sawtooths ...'_ So here, no article.